# How to select certain fields in the response body when making http call using TypeScript and Axios

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I am very new to JavaScript and TypeScript and have always been coding in statically typed language, e.g. Java, Kotlin, Scala.

So, I am trying to convert a response body received from a http call using Axios to an interface I have defined. See the following code.

```
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

const token: string = 'token';
const url: string = 'https://some.api.website.com/users'

interface User {
    id: bigint,
    startDate: string
};

const axiosRequestConfig: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`}
};

async function getUsers() {
    return await axios.get(url, axiosRequestConfig)
    .then(res => res.data)
};

async function main() {
    let res = await getUsers();
    console.log(res);
}

main();
```

The `res.data` contains something like this. The actual response contains a lot more fields than the example below, hence, why I want to select which fields I need rather than getting them all first.

```
[
  {
    "id": 123456,
    "employment_start_date": "1989-12-17",
    "report_department_id": 111,
    "active": true,
    "time_zone": "Australia/Brisbane",
    "utc_offset": 36000,
    "created_at": 1430715548
  }
]
```

How do I parse the response body and cast it to the interface `User` I defined? In other words, I want to `getUsers()` function signature to return `Promise<User[]>`.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `await axios.get<User>`

Comment: I tried `await axios.get<User>` and `await axios.get<User[]>` and both still return the whole object rather than just the fields as defined in the `User` interface.

Comment: Oh!  You mean you want fewer fields to be returned from the server.  You can't tell the server what to return, unless there's some feature of the server to control that.  But that would be server-specific.  It should be safe to just ignore the fields you don't want.

Comment: i see. so in my case, how can I modify the function so it would just return the list of `User` objects?

Comment: The server is returning more than you need, but that's OK and you can ignore the extra fields.  It's common to do this.  Your type declaration doesn't actually control what's there, it just **asserts** to TypeScript what's there (it will believe anything you tell it).  Rather than the `console.log`, try actually using the return value in code and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I didn't notice it was an array in my first comment, so it would be `await axios.get<User[]>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to change your method like this:

```
async function getUsers() {
    return (await axios.get<User[]>(url, axiosRequestConfig)).data;
};
```

You will still see **all** the data if you use `console.log` on the result, but your program can simply ignore the other fields and use the fields from `User` in a type-safe way.  This assumes that the fields of `User` match the actual response from the server exactly, and I'm not sure if that's the case.

If it's important to strip out other fields (eg. if you need to serialize the result to save elsewhere and you want to save space), then you could modify it like this:

```
async function getUsers(): User[] {
    return (await axios.get<User[]>(url, axiosRequestConfig)).data
        .map(rawData => ({id: rawData.id, startDate: rawData.employment_start_date}));
};
```

That way you're plucking out only the fields that are in the `User` type and returning them.  It also gives you the opportunity to rename fields as I did with `startDate` vs `employment_start_date`.

Here is a [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChkHLAAmAXMgEbADmoYANPoemHFGACJyTktSjVcAXwDcuXHHQBPEAmQwArrLDAA9iGRwAHmvTwA1hGoQwACgCUOJgQTqWyYtzjIAvMgDaTPIWQAiEr7kAIwATADMACwArABsjD6+EAC2AA4ANqpSSRDgAPosbGC5jpCBfkEAnAAcFQC0ofUA7L7xhL5QECmq7MWdhdl5AcFBQa0EvogqAG4QZWBQChBjfirZuQBe6rPkvgCCCnxwacBwAPQAQvzoFHAgs8u+CmAIuaowMJhgZWExAAz-DwQHW4EGIuW4ZSCETCv0aQSiUQiVSYQlwAF0xB0wAooBpsCU4KjUZIZHJFMo1BpjGAMNB0BYrD4sTiNKY4AB3ODAMCaHSqPRwQzUizmAB0BOshFFSTgKVMUA5XFYrgAfMhTNgSOQFeylXBRSR6MgCuwlRBtYqnKLkulMgMiiaiiUIEJzOYxKJxCTZPIlAgVOpkDLQAzvIQ0iZkB10K5NJzuchqbSoPT3ZLbCB0KoI6KMtR5RB0GnUbhgyALCIgA) example for the record (faked out axios).

Comment: it does not work for me. it actually returns nothing. i call it inside the `main()` function as per my question.

Comment: i made it work like this.

```
return await axios.get(url, axiosRequestConfig)
.then(res => res.data)
    .then((data: any[]) => data.map(d => {
        const userId: UserId = {
            id: d.id
        };
        return userId;
    }))
```

Comment: My mistake was omitting parentheses around the axios call when I compressed your `.then` syntax into a more compact form.  Should have been `await (axios etc).data` not `await axios etc.data`.  Corrected for posterity.

Comment: ok that works. just wondering, comparing your answer to mine, i noticed you are using parentheses whereas mine uses `return` to emit the result. is this a convention in JS?

Comment: It's a short form in TypeScript and modern JS.  `() => "hello"` is a short form for `() => {return "hello";}`.  It's largely preference but people I think tend to prefer the short form.  If returning an object, you have wrap in parentheses, too, eg. `() => ({a:1})` so that it doesn't think you're writing a function body.